# Flutter iOS build on Codemagic with GetSocial.im failed

Tags: ios, flutter, podfile, codemagic

I'm developing mobile App for Android & iOS.
Using Android Studio, Flutter/Dart. Code on GitHub.

Build for Android on my Windows PC and Google Play (without Xcode).
Build for iOS based on Codemagic.

Everything was fine.

Now I'm integrating GetSocial.im. It's working OK on Android and has the following error on Codemagic /iOS.

```
/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-BC363FF324E52E62005DC28B.sh: line 2: /Users/builder/clone/ios/getsocial-sdk7.sh: No such file or directory
```

I added the following phase to project.pbxproj

```
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /* ShellScript */ = {
        isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
        buildActionMask = 2147483647;
        files = (
        );
        inputPaths = (
        );
        outputPaths = (
        );
        runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        shellPath = /bin/sh;
        shellScript = "${PROJECT_DIR}/getsocial-sdk7.sh --app-id=MyIDxxxxxxxxx\n";
    };
```

Any idea how to resolved the problem?

**Update**

I added the script getsocial-sdk7.sh file to IOS directory and looks like the file was found.
Now i have a new error

/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edaimyiflreloheqntgnhkmwcclv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-BC363FF324E52E62005DC28B.sh: line 2: /Users/builder/clone/ios/getsocial-sdk7.sh: Permission denied

Where is permission definitions?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the file `ios/getsocial-sdk7.sh` doesn't exist when the XCode generated script is trying to invoke it, so you might want to check that it in fact is at that relative path in your Flutter apps's git repo.

Answer (score 0):

With the help off @Maks from `GetSocial`

I run on Android Studio Terminal the command

```
git add --chmod=+x -- getsocial-sdk7.sh
git commit -m"XXX"
git push
```